# hashCode changes each time the object is created

Tags: java, hashcode

There is something that escapes me about hashCode. I know that if i override
equals, then i must override hashCode too. I also know that if two objects are
equal, then the hashCode of the two objects must be equal. If the fields that are checked in the equals method don't change, than the hashCode should not change, right?

If so, then i can't understand why each time i create an instance of the object below, i get a different hashCode:

```
public class Effect {

    private long timestamp;
    private int damage;
    private SquareType squareType;

    public Effect(long timestamp, int damage, SquareType squareType) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.squareType = squareType;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }

    public SquareType getSquareType() {
        return squareType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Effect effect = (Effect) o;

        if (getDamage() != effect.getDamage()) return false;
        return getSquareType() == effect.getSquareType();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getDamage();
        result = 31 * result + (getSquareType() != null ? getSquareType().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String ret = "Effect hashcode: " + hashCode();
        return ret;
    }
}
```

In the code i create this kind of objects continuously over time. The only field that changes each time is "timestamp", but the two other fields don't change (unless there is a specific event). What happens is that the hashCode value is always different, even if "damage" and "SquareType" are the same. 
I don't use "timestamp" in my equals and hashCode, so i can't understand why i get this behavior.

**Update**

This is SquareType:

```
public enum SquareType {
    FIRE, WIND, WATER, EARTH
}
```

**Update 2**

For example, if i create 10 instances of Effect, i iterate over them and i
print them (toString() returns the hashCode value) i get 10 different values.

If two instances of Effect have the same "damage" and "SquareType" then they must be equal and have the same hashCode.

**Update 3**

The effects are created like this:

```
@Override
public void friendlyFire(BaseBullet bullet, BaseSquare square) {
    square.notifyFriendlyFire(new Effect(TimeUtils.millis(),
            square.getDamage(), square.getSquareType()), new MyKey(square.getUniqueID()));
}
```

The only Effect's field that changes is the timestamp, and i don't use it in equals and hashCode.

```
public void notifyFriendlyFire(Effect newEffect, MyKey key) {
    // System.out.println("The map contains the key? " + effectMap.containsKey(key));
    if(effectMap.containsKey(key)) {
        Effect oldEffect = effectMap.get(key);
        System.out.println(newEffect);
        if(!oldEffect.equals(newEffect)) {
            System.out.println("old effect changed!");
            // remove the old effect
            removeEffect(oldEffect);
            // update the map with the new effect
            effectMap.put(key, newEffect); // 
            // apply the new effect
            applyEffect(newEffect);
        }
    }
    else {
        // new effect
        effectMap.put(key, newEffect);
        applyEffect(newEffect);
    }
}
```

The check "if(!oldEffect.equals(newEffect))" is always true, even if damage and type are the same.

**Update 4**

I've found the bug. Damage increases continuously. Now i've just to figure out why...

Comment: Could you post `SquareType`? It probably doesn't override hashCode.

Comment: How is `SquareType`s hashCode calculated?

Comment: SquareType is an Enumeration, what should i do?

Comment: Could you post a full code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Have you tried writing some test code that creates two instances with the same values, calling hashCode() on those instances, and debugging in and seeing what the component hashes in the hash code are (or logging them out if you're not familiar with the debugger) to try and see which component is actually differing?

Comment: why don't you simply post the demonstration code as Tunaki asked? Maybe you are doing something silly like creating the Effect objects with damage and timestamp parameter changed

Comment: Just to be sure: In the toString method print also returns also the damage and square type to be sure that the objects are equals as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt at approximating your implementation:

```
package cruft;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Equals and hashCode test
 * Creation date 1/16/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826585/hashcode-changes-each-time-the-object-is-created
 */
public class OverrideDemo {

    private long timestamp;
    private int damage;
    private SquareType squareType;


    public OverrideDemo(int damage, SquareType squareType) {
        this(damage, squareType, new Date().getTime());
    }

    public OverrideDemo(int damage, SquareType squareType, long timestamp) {
        if (squareType == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("square type cannot be null");
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.damage = damage;
        this.squareType = squareType;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public int getDamage() {
        return damage;
    }

    public SquareType getSquareType() {
        return squareType;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) { return true; }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) { return false; }

        OverrideDemo that = (OverrideDemo) o;

        if (damage != that.damage) { return false; }
        return squareType == that.squareType;

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = damage;
        result = 31 * result + squareType.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OverrideDemo{" +
                "timestamp=" + timestamp +
                ", damage=" + damage +
                ", squareType=" + squareType +
                '}';
    }
}

enum SquareType { FIRE, WIND, WATER, EARTH }
```

Here's a Junit test that shows how the methods behave.  All tests pass; I think this implementation is correct.

```
package cruft;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

/**
 * Junit test demonstrates testing equals and hashcode contract
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 1/16/2016.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34826585/hashcode-changes-each-time-the-object-is-created
 */
public class OverrideDemoTest {

    @Test
    public void testEquals_Null() {
        OverrideDemo x = new OverrideDemo(5, SquareType.EARTH);
        Assert.assertFalse(x.equals(null));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_Reflexive() {
        OverrideDemo x = new OverrideDemo(5, SquareType.EARTH);
        Assert.assertTrue(x.equals(x));
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_Symmetric() {
        OverrideDemo x = new OverrideDemo(5, SquareType.EARTH);
        OverrideDemo y = new OverrideDemo(5, SquareType.EARTH);
        Assert.assertTrue(x.equals(y));
        Assert.assertTrue(y.equals(x));
        Assert.assertTrue(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_Transitive() {
        OverrideDemo x = new OverrideDemo(5, SquareType.EARTH);
        OverrideDemo y = new OverrideDemo(5, SquareType.EARTH);
        OverrideDemo z = new OverrideDemo(5, SquareType.EARTH);
        Assert.assertTrue(x.equals(y));
        Assert.assertTrue(y.equals(z));
        Assert.assertTrue(z.equals(x));
        Assert.assertTrue(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode());
        Assert.assertTrue(y.hashCode() == z.hashCode());
        Assert.assertTrue(z.hashCode() == x.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_DifferentDamage_NotEqual() {
        OverrideDemo x = new OverrideDemo(5, SquareType.EARTH);
        OverrideDemo y = new OverrideDemo(10, SquareType.EARTH);
        Assert.assertFalse(x.equals(y));
        Assert.assertFalse(y.equals(x));
        Assert.assertFalse(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testEquals_DifferentSquareType_NotEqual() {
        OverrideDemo x = new OverrideDemo(10, SquareType.EARTH);
        OverrideDemo y = new OverrideDemo(10, SquareType.FIRE);
        Assert.assertFalse(x.equals(y));
        Assert.assertFalse(y.equals(x));
        Assert.assertFalse(x.hashCode() == y.hashCode());
    }
}
```